# Always mount a disk (flashdrive) with a particular label to the same mountpoint

Tags: mount, permissions

I have an external HDD and when I plug it in, I'd like it that Ubuntu always mounted it to a particular mountpoint and with particular read/write permissions.

To be more precise, I have an external drive with a partition called "Backup" (`/dev/sdb1`) and I'd like it to me mounted to `/media/Backup` with read-only permissions. What's the easiest way to do that?

Comment: That is what the file `/etc/fstab` is for. Include a line with the unique disk ID, the mount point, and options like read-only permissions. At the time the drive is connected, the system will mount it as specified in `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: what type is the drive?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trouble automounting an SD card on Trusty](http://askubuntu.com/questions/679435/trouble-automounting-an-sd-card-on-trusty)

Comment: Snitko, Did the below answer help?  If yes, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Answer (score 0):

All of the parameters of the following how-to are explained in the [official Ubuntu documentation for fstab](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab)

1. Insert the USB drive
2. Go to a terminal and type `sudo blkid` and you should receive the following output:

   ```
   /dev/sdb1: LABEL="BACKUP" UUID="mmmmmmmm-nnnn-oooo-pppp-qqqqqqqq" TYPE="szFileSystem"
   ```

If the label does not say "BACKUP", you made a mistake in assigning a name to your stick. Open `gparted`, unmount the volume and set the correct label.

3. In the same terminal, type `sudo md /media/BACKUP`
4. and: `chmod -w /media/BACKUP`
5. and: `sudo nano /etc/fstab/`
6. Download a nice **square** back-up icon and save it to `/usr/share/pixmaps` in png format.
7. At the end of the file add:

   ```
   UUID=mmmmmmmm-nnnn-oooo-pppp-qqqqqqqq /media/BACKUP szFileSystem nosuid,nodev,noexec,users,nobootwait,nofail,ro,comment=x-gvfs-show,comment=x-gvfs-icon=NiceBackupIcon,comment=x-gvfs-name=BACKUP   0   2
   ```

where:

- `mmmmmmmm-nnnn-oooo-pppp-qqqqqqqq` is the UUID from step 2
- `szFileSystem` is the file system from step 2
- `NiceBackupIcon` is the icon you downloaded in step 6 (note: no png file extension)

Comment: Don't thank me!  ;-) Just click the little grey check-mark under the "0" now.  If you do not like my answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the 0, turning it into beautiful green and if you *really* like my answer, click on the little grey checkmark *and* the little up-arrow...  If you have any further questions, go to http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask

Comment: Not in a running system. ;) http://askubuntu.com/a/679669/367165