# Trouble automounting an SD card on Trusty

Tags: 14.04, fstab, automount

I need an SD card to be mounted unattended, as soon as it is inserted in its slot. Usual enough, but the prbm is it does not get mounted and I am missing why.

In `/etc/fstab`:

```
#Entry for /dev/mmcblk0p1 :
UUID=_____   /mnt/SD-root ext3 defaults,nofail,umask=0027,utf8,comment=x-gvfs-show,x-gvfs-name=SD-root 0 2
```

**EDIT-1:**  *I also tried replacing `/mnt/` with `/media/myname/` above, and including the options `user,uid=1000` (that's me) or `users`, to no avail.*

Mount point is either `/mnt/SD-root` or `/media/myname/SD-root`. Mountpoint ownership is set to "root : adm".

```
$ ls -Al /mnt/ | grep -e 'SD-root'
1 drwxr-x--- 3 root adm 1024 Sep 25 16:51 SD-root/
```

Right now the only way for a non-root user to mount the SD card is to:

```
$  sudo mount /dev/mmcblk0p1 /mnt/SD-root/
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: /etc/fstab is for automounting when you boot not for automounting when you insert the card

Comment: @Mchid: Not precisely. `/etc/fstab` is read at boot time when `mountall` is invoked to mount filesystems and detected block-devices are listed and don't have option `noauto` set . However `/etc/fstab` can also be and is used to list mounting options for devices not meant to be mounted at boot.  Isn't that's the raison d'être of the option `noauto` ?

Comment: Then why doesn't it work?

Comment: It doesn't work because:  */etc/fstab is for automounting when you boot not for automounting when you insert the card*

Comment: **@mchid:** :D :D :D   **Cbhibe:** two words: `udev` rules!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To mount the card automatically at `/mnt` in a running system you could use an additional `udev` rule. Without the rule, the card is mounted in `/media/$USER/…` and `/dev/disk/…`.

---

The following script and udev rule create a folder in `/mnt` and mount a the partition with a defined UUID. In the current version, the mountpoint is the label of the mounted partition. I personally think, that's a bad idea. I would prefer the UUID and not the label, but the OP wanted this solution.

1. The script

   - Create a script in `/usr/local/bin`

     ```
     sudo nano /usr/local/bin/mount_by
     ```
   - Add the code below

     ```sh
     #!/bin/sh
     export mount_point="/mnt/$1"
     existing_device=$(awk '$2 == ENVIRON["mount_point"] {print $1; exit}' < /proc/mounts)
     if [ -n "$existing_device" ]; then
       exit 1
     fi
     mkdir -p "$mount_point"
     sleep 1 # Perhaps not necessary, but in the test with the OP it was necessary
     mount "/dev/disk/by-uuid/$2" "$mount_point"
     exit 0
     ```
   - Make the script executable

     ```
     sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/mount_by
     ```
2. The udev rule

   - Create a new rule

     ```
     sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/99-myrules.rules
     ```
   - Add the code below

     ```
     ENV{ID_FS_UUID}=="c8bf306d-3d5d-4878-8045-e4087494eff0", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/mount_by '%E{ID_PART_ENTRY_NAME}' '%E{ID_FS_UUID}'"
     ```

     or if your drive hasn't the `ID_PART_ENTRY_NAME`, try `ID_FS_LABEL`
   - Suppose that the partition is **`/dev/sdc1`** Replace the value for **`ENV{ID_FS_UUID}==`** above with the output of

     ```
     udevadm info /dev/sdc1 | awk -F= '/ID_FS_UUID=/ {print $2}'
     ```
3. Restart udev

   ```
   sudo service udev restart
   ```
4. Plugin your SD card and you should see something like this

   ```
   % ls -la /mnt
   total 12
   drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Okt  6 19:29 .
   drwxr-xr-x 25 root root 4096 Sep 29 17:04 ..
   drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 Okt  6 19:31 Label1
   ```

Comment: Can you give me pointers to a wiki or else to learn about udev rules ?

Comment: @Cbhihe: "Yes, expand your answer" = "I'll click ☑" (which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)) so you can expand the answer...

Comment: @Fabby: Gee ! I was waiting for you to answer, just so I could select his ! Bear with me until tomorrow. Till then my hands are full.

Comment: @Cbhihe: I'm not A.B. ...  Just dropping by because I didn't see an accepted answer!  **;-)**

Comment: I can't read your dropbox. Please use http://paste.ubuntu.com/

Comment: Please check the new part in my answer. Check the difference here http://askubuntu.com/posts/679669/revisions

Comment: Ok, test it again. I have changed the script and the rule a little bit. Works for me.

Comment: And **you need** the `export mount_point="/mnt/$1"` to use it in the `awk` script or use `awk -v … `.

Comment: @A.B. I found the tiny problem that remained !  The udev rule initial match on the event dev tag `KERNEL=="s???"` is wrong. It should be `KERNEL=="mm*"` when dealing with an mmcblk type SD card.  --- Can you just modify your udev rule so I can mark yr answer as correct ? Thank you for your help A.B. I appreciate yr time and explanation.

Comment: Great :) Now I'm happy. Maybe it's better without the `KERNEL...` parameter. Delete the thing and try it again.

Comment: I have changed my answer. And if it's correct, don't forget to accept my answer :)

Comment: .. and don't forget to add the `sleep 1` before the `mkdir -p ...` in yr answer. Without that the script breaks. Tx.

Answer (score 1):

I setup fresh new Ubuntu 14.04 to test this. The SD card formated as EXT3.
 The is automounted.

Here output of `mount` with different setups

- With default setup, no fstab entry:

  ```
  /dev/mmcblk0p1 on /media/sneetsher/test0 type ext3 (rw,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks2)
  ```
- With fstab:

  ```
  /dev/mmcblk0p1                            /media/test0    ext3    nodev,noexec,comment=x-gvfs-show 0       0
  ```

  mounted as:

  ```
  /dev/mmcblk0p1 on /media/test0 type ext3 (rw,noexec,nodev)
  ```
- With fstab:

  ```
  /dev/mmcblk0p1                            /media/test0    ext3    defaults,nofail,umask=0027,utf8,comment=x-gvfs-show,x-gvfs-name=SD-root 0 2
  ```

  Found dmesg errors:

  ```
  [ 3339.729139] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p1): Unrecognized mount option "umask=0027" or missing value
  ```

  removed, then found:

  ```
  [ 3410.950108] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p1): Unrecognized mount option "utf8" or missing value
  ```

  removed, then found:

  ```
  [ 3490.129696] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p1): Unrecognized mount option "x-gvfs-name=SD-root" or missing value
  ```

  changed to:

  ```
  /dev/mmcblk0p1                            /media/test0    ext3    defaults,nofail,comment=x-gvfs-show,comment=x-gvfs-name=SD-root 0 2
  ```

  mounted as:

  ```
  /dev/mmcblk0p1 on /media/test0 type ext3 (rw,_netdev)
  ```

  `x-gvfs-name` is effective as it shown as `SD-root` in nautilus.

Did I miss some thing from your setup?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time Sneetsher. As evidenced by yr tests `utf8` is not a valid option for ext4 or ext3. Also the `umask=----` options spells trouble. That I don't comprehend. Nevertheless at least for the time being, my preferred mount route is that proposed by @A.B., i.e. with udev rules.

Comment: Could you reference from where did you get those options, I could find them in `man mount` for some other file systems but not for ext3.

Comment: You'll find everything in mount(8), I think.

Answer (score 0):

Just take the ownership of the folder /media/test0.

> chown user.user /media/test0